# Sharing NpgsqlConnection with all repositories

Tags: garbage-collection, connection, repository, unit-of-work, npgsql

Context : 
I am trying to understand the UnitOfWork pattern and its relation with repositories.

But I have a basic questions related to the NpgsqlConnnection class.

My UnitOfWork contains a private field member which is a NpgsqlConnection : uow_connection.
And my repository has a constructor that takes an NpgsqlConnection as parameter and saves it in a field member too.

**[1] Is it ok to have that kind of design ?** (sharing the uow_connection among **all** the required repositories).

Since my repository ***does not*** implement IDisposable and the NpgsqlConnection seems to be an unmanaged ressource, if the garbage collector releases my repository object, **[3] will the connection still be alive ?**

I am worrying about the fact that all the needed repository for the current transaction will share the same uow_connection passed by value.

(***[2] Is it ok to think that if IDisposable is implemented, so it's an unmanaged ressource or a managed ressource can implements IDisposable and still be a managed ressource ?)***

I labelled my questions so it will be easy to reference them.

Thanks all for taking time to read my question.

Answer (score 0):

[1]. No. Npgsql isn't thread safe and you could end up using your shared connection between more than one thread. Threading problems are the most difficult to track because they tend to happen when you expect the least. (They also tend to appear more in your production environment :) ) You should use the design of create a connection, open it and then close it. Npgsql pooling will take care of getting you a ready connection whenever your want.

[3]. Yes, your connection will be leaked until the the garbage collector cleans up the objects without any strong reference.

[2] Normally IDisposable should only be implemented by classes which contain unmanaged resources so the garbage collector will be able to handle them correctly. Check this documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx

I hope it helps.